# Operand data type date is invalid for subtract operator when calculate average date

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate average customers will order

[image]

but when i calculate there's have a problem, mine is:

```
SELECT CustomerID, (MAX(SalesDate) - MIN(SalesDate)) / (COUNT(*) - 1)
  FROM TrSalesHeader
 GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

and i've message "Operand data type date is invalid for subtract operator."

can anyone help me to solve this problem? thankyou

Comment: 'I want to calculate average customers will order' ? Please clarify. And add sample date and expected outcome as text.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have basic syntax error.
Use `Count(*)`

```
SELECT 
  CustomerID,
  (MAX(SalesDate) - MIN(SalesDate) / (COUNT(*) - 1) )
FROM
  TrSalesHeader 
GROUP BY CustomerID 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Since you have not mentioned your desired OP. This is only what I can get upto

Comment: hai thankyou for answering my question. but still i got message "Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query"

Answer (score 0):

I assume you calculate average by calculating the difference in the max/min dates and dividing by total records. Use the default function to do this instead of subtracting directly

```
SELECT CustomerID, DATEDIFF(MAX(SalesDate),MIN(SalesDate)) / (COUNT(*) - 1)
  FROM TrSalesHeader
 GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: hiii thankyou for answering my question, but i still got message The datediff function requires 3 argument(s).

Comment: @TasyaFauziaFitriasari are you using mysql?

Comment: DATEDIFF(interval, date1, date2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customerID, (DATEDIFF(dayofyear, MIN(orderDate), MAX(orderDate))/ (COUNT(*) -1)) AS 'date_diff',  
FROM orders
GROUP BY customerID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This answer would be better with explanation, and the DATEDIFF parameters don't appear to be MySQL syntax.